# Why are all of my jobs in Parse stuck on pending?

Tags: parse-platform

My jobs all are pending but the parse status page says everything is up and running? Is there anything I could have done to cause this or is it a Parse bug?

[image: Parse Screenshot]

Comment: I am facing the same issue from couple of days. Did you able to resolve this issue? Let me know if you had anything on this issue. Thanks

Comment: It seems to be a Parse issue intermittently that eventually goes away on its own. I have only encountered it for hours at a time though and not days.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my case also issue goes after 2 days. I think parse team working on migrating or trying few things on their server. So randomly few things stopped working but eventually they made it working again.